# Does the Fourier transform of a smooth $L^2$ function decay rapidly at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

For $L^1$ functions, there is a correspondence through the Fourier Transform between functions which are smooth and functions which decay rapidly at infinity. More precisely, if $f$ is a smooth $L^1$ function, $\hat{f}$ is an $L^\infty$ function which decays faster than any polynomial at infinity, and conversely, if $g$ is an $L^\infty$ function which decays faster than any polynomial at infinity, then the inverse fourier transform of $g$ is $L^1$ and smooth.

For $L^2$ functions, there is a difficulty. The Fourier transform formula is no longer valid on individual functions. It only is defined on the $L^2$ classes of functions.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a standard way to extend "decays rapidly at infinity" to $L^2$ classes of functions?
2. Assuming (1), is there a 1-1 correspondence between classes of $L^2$ functions with a smooth representative and classes of $L^2$ functions which decay rapidly at infinity?

Comment: I might just not know the result, but while I see that $\hat{f} \in C_0$ if $f \in L^1$, I can't see why it decays faster than any polynomial (unless it is a Schwartz function, obviously). Why is that true?

Comment: Also, what is an $L^2$ class of functions? ($L^p$ spaces are always technically defined as classes of functions, given that they can differ on a set of measure zero.)

Comment: In fact, the situation with L2 functions is even nicer: A function is L2 if and only if it's Fourier transform is L2. in fact parsevall's tells us that the L2 norm is preserved.

Comment: I mean exactly that: L^2 is made up of equivalence classes of functions that differ only on a set of measure zero.

Comment: The Fourier transform of a smooth $L^1$ function decays faster than any polynomial, but this is not true for a general $L^1$ function.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom This is true, but it does not address the question. The question is about the duality between smoothness and quick decay.

Comment: "Smoothness" should be mentioned in the title, right now it's a little misleading: upon reading it I thought of $e^{-|t|}$, whose Fourier transform is the pdf of the Cauchy distribution $1/1+x^2$, an $L^2$ function which does not decay rapdily.

Comment: You are absolutely right. That was an oversight on my part. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> if $f$ is a smooth $L^1$ function, $\hat{f}$ is an $L^\infty$ function which decays faster than any polynomial at infinity

This is not true as stated. *Unquantified* smoothness does not lead to quantitative conclusions. Indeed, the properties of $\hat f$ that you claimed imply $\hat f\in L^2$, hence $f\in L^2$. But a smooth $L^1$ function need not be in $L^2$. Another line of counterexamples comes from functions like $f(x) = \sin(e^x)/(1+x^4)$. This is a smooth function in $L^1\cap L^2$, but since $f'\notin L^2$, it follows that $\xi \hat f(\xi)\notin L^2$, hence $\hat f$ does not decay all that quickly.

What is true is that a smooth $L^1$ function such that all of its derivatives are *also* in $L^1$ has rapidly decaying Fourier transform.

Now consider a smooth $L^2$ function $f$ whose derivatives are in $L^2$.  Then $$(1+|\xi|)^k \hat f(\xi)\in L^2\quad \text{ for all }  k\ge 0\tag{1} $$ and the converse holds too. Indeed, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, 
$$
\int |g(\xi)|\le \sqrt{\int (1+|\xi|)^{-2}\,d \xi}\sqrt{\int (1+|\xi|)^2 |g(\xi)|^2\,d\xi}
$$
Hence $(1)$ implies $(1+|\xi|)^k \hat f(\xi)\in L^1 $ for all $k\in L^1$, and the latter property yields the smoothness of $f$.

But one can build $\hat f$ that satisfies $(1)$ and is not even bounded: e.g., 
$$
\hat f(\xi) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \chi_{[n,n+e^{-n}]}
$$
(and get $f$ from it by the inverse transform).  So, the answer to the question posed is negative.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the next question is "What is the image of the smooth $L^2$ functions under the Fourier transform?", since this guess was wrong.

Comment: It's described by (1). (Again, assuming all derivatives are also in $L^2$)

Comment: Right, but I don't want to assume all derivatives are in $L^2$. Actually I'm looking both for the image of all smooth functions, and the image of all smooth functions whose first derivative is in $L^2$. But your answer has given me a lot to think about.