# Let $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ be such that both $f$ and $f'$ belong to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Show that $\hat{f} \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The exercise is the following:

> Let $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ be such that both $f$ and $f'$ belong to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Show that $\hat{f} \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

What I want to prove is that $\int_\mathbb{R} |\hat{f}(\xi)|d\xi  < +\infty$ but I do not know how to proceed; I have started saying that $\int_\mathbb{R} |\hat{f}(\xi)|d\xi = \int_\mathbb{R} | \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)e^{-2\pi i \xi x} dx|d\xi $ and then the idea was to use the properties of Fourier transform and of its derivatives such as:

- $f'(x) \hat{\to} 2\pi i \xi\hat{f}(\xi)$
- $-2\pi i x f(x) \hat{\to}\hat{f'}(\xi) $

but these properties require $f$ to be in the Schwartz space, that is not our case.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The formula for the Fourier transform of $f'$ is wrong. The factor $\xi$ is missing.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc thanks, corrected!

Comment: Both $f$ and $xf$ are $L^2$, then use Cauchy Schwarz

Comment: @reuns: why is $x\mapsto xf(x)\in L^2$? If $f$ had derivative in the sense of $L_2$ ($\frac{\tau_hf-f}{h}$ converges in $L_2$, then that would be the case. It might be the the hypothesis in the OP imply that $f'$ (in the usual sense) is also a derivative in the $L_2$ sense, but this is not clear.

Comment: @OliverDíaz $f'\in C(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^2,$ so its Fourier transform belongs to $L^2.$

Comment: I just misread, $\hat{f}$ and $\xi \hat{f}$ are in $L^2$

Comment: @OliverDíaz I understand that $f'$ is the usual derivative. By assumptions it is continuous and square integrable.

Comment: @OliverDíaz The link refers to another question. Here we need to show that $ \hat{f}$ is integrable. As suggested by reuns we can make use of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality applied to the product  $$\hat{f}(\xi)=(1+\xi^2)^{-1/2} \cdot (1+\xi^2)^{1/2}  \hat{f}(\xi)$$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: from the link (or rather the answer by user "Desintegration by Parts" it follows that $f^2$ (and this $f$) is in $C_0$ and that $constant\cdot s\hat{f}(s)=\widehat{f'}(s)\in L_2$. In particular this also shows that $f$ is differentiable in the sense of $L_2$ ($f'$ being the $L_2$-derivative too). Maybe you want to write a solution to the OP.

Comment: @OliverDíaz This a standard exercise and I am afraid this question has been asked many times. See the answer formula (1) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511897/does-the-fourier-transform-of-a-smooth-l2-function-decay-rapidly-at-infinity

Comment: @OliverDíaz I do not mind if you post an answer. By the way how do you attach a link in the comments section  ? I usually copy the entire link, but that's ugly.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: I am writing one now. to attach a link, enclose the word where the link will be anchored between square brackets, follows by the link enclosed by regular brackets, that is [Here](the link).

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the exchanges among @reuns, @RyszardSzwarc and myself here is one possible solution:

The assumptions of the problem imply that

1. $f^2$ (and thus $f$) is in $C_0$. See for instance this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4164971/121671).
2. $2\pi i s\hat{f}(s)=\widehat{f'}(s)\in L_2$. See for example this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1377362/121671).

The conclusion follows as indicated by reuns and Ryszard:

$$\hat{f}(s)=(1+s^2)^{-1/2}(1+s^2)^{1/2}\hat{f}(s)$$

and so,

$$\int|\hat{f}|\leq\Big(\int(1+s^2)^{-1}\,ds\Big)^{1/2}\Big(\int(1+s^2)|\hat{f}(s)|^2\,ds\Big)^{1/2}<\infty$$

Comment: In formula $2.$ the first occurence of $s$ should be removed.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: I just removed the additional $s$. Now it has the correct form.

Answer (score 1):

One observation: The assumption $f\in\mathcal{C}^1$ can be weakened to $f$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$. To see this, define  $h=f^2$. Then $h\in L_1$ and $h'=2ff'\in L_1$. It follows that for any numbers $a<b$
\begin{align}
h(b)-h(a)=\int^b_a h'(t)\,dt
\end{align}
(See theorem 7.21 in Rudin, W., *Real and Complex Analysis*, Third edition, page 149, which does not make reference to absolute continuity). Then the limits $A=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}h(x)$ and $B=\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}h(x)$ exits. The integrbility of $h=f^2$ implies that $A=B=0$. Hence,  $f\in\mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R})$.

An application of Plancherel's theorem and Lebesgue integration by parts gives
$$\widehat{f'}(t)=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int^R_{-R}e^{-2\pi x t}f'(x)\,dx=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}2\pi i t\int^R_{-R}e^{-2\pi i tx}f(x)\,dx=2\pi it\widehat{f}(t)$$
The convergence on the  is in $L_2$, and pointwise along a subsequence $R_k\rightarrow\infty$. Therefore
$2\pi i t\widehat{f}(t)=\widehat{f'}(t)\in L_2$. The rest is as indicated in the Community wiki answer